# Xubuntu 22.04 crashes regularly

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, crash

I have a new laptop, 20 gigs of ram with a fresh Xubuntu 22.04 install on it.  Apps crash regularly, without warning -- web browsers, word documents.  Everything.  It's the least stable system I have ever tried to use.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue please?

*edit*

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-2: Sonix USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon Vega 3 Graphics (raven2 LLVM 13.0.1 DRM 3.42
  5.15.0-43-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card? If so, which card? Can you edit the question to add more information?

Comment: Hi Archisman.  What information do you need?  Let me know and I'll happily add it!